# Change what a class is extending from Java

Tags: java, timer, extends, timertask

In Java, I have a need to easily switch out what a class is extending. To be precise, I have to deploy my application to two different platforms where one support Java Timers and TimerTasks, and the other has it's own implementations (also called Timer and Timertask with the same method names but their own implementation).

Essentially, I need to be able to easily switch between TimerTask classes for this use case:

`private class TimerTaskImpl extends TimerTask {`

^^^ where in the above on one platform TimerTask will be Java's, and in the other TimerTask will be the manual implementation used by that platform.

Comment: Use `interface`s and factory patterns

Comment: Couldn't you do something like have two different versions of the class that extend the two different timers, then have an adapter that makes the interface consistent, then use the adapter?

Comment: I can't see an easy way to do this. The main issue here is that the TimerTaskImpl is a nested class and it's run() method uses objects from the class it is nested in.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like this?

```
interface MyTimerTask {
    ...
}

class TimerTaskImpl1 extends java.util.TimerTask implements MyTimerTask {

}

class TimerTaskImpl2 extends other.TimerTask implements MyTimerTask {

}


public class TimerTaskFactory {

    public static MyTimerTask createTimerTask() {
        MyTimerTask timertask = null;
        try {
            Class.forName( "java.util.TimerTask" );
            timertask = new TimerTaskImpl1();

        } catch( ClassNotFoundException _ex ) {
            //java.util.TimerTask class isn't there!
            timertask = new TimerTaskImpl2();
        }

        return timertask;
    }
}
```

... or something similar depending on your TimerTaskImpl.

Comment: I like the idea, although I run into the issue that this interface would need access to the class the TimerTask is being used in. Although not impossible, I am trying to essentially decouple the dependency on other.TimerTask and I believe this does not quite accomplish that.

Comment: I do not see where the problem is with that? You can for example use some sort of delegate that forwards the call to the delegate.